# Easy way to apply calculated/inline styles to html?

Tags: html, wordpress, stylesheet

Really annoying situation, and maybe there is an easier solution.. but I basically have a simple table I have styled in the general format:

```
<style type="text/css">
  table.master_table {
    ... global table styling
  }
  .master_table td {
    ... master table td styling
  } 
  .master_table td.dv {
    ... td dv style
  }
  .. more styling
</style>

<table class="master_table">
  <tbody>
 <tr>
   <td class="dv">
     .. nothing special
 </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the problem is the server doesn't support the "style" element so I need to manually apply the style to each level i.e.:

```
<table style="... global table styling">
  <tbody>
 <tr>
   <td style="td styling;td dv style">
     .. nothing special
 </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any programs that can do this?  Or is there any easier way to do this? I basically have a Wordpress.com blog that looks beautiful, in Live Writer because of some custom styling but as soon as I post, it strips out the style block.  As a test I went through an manually did some of the above and it works, its just insanely painful and error prone.

Comment: Can you get a new server? What kind of server removes styles?

Comment: Wordpress.com  ;)  i could host it, but i rarely use custom styled tables in the blog.

Comment: Can you link to a stylesheet that you are hosting elsewhere?

Comment: I don't think they allow you to do that.  I think my options are to pay for edit css capabilities, and then just put the styles in the global "safecss" style sheet, or to do the above and just apply the styles to the html manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found an online solution called ["emogrifier"](http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/)

Works well, all you have to do is enter css, then enter html and it will output inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on wordpress.com i do not think you can control the css or anyother file.

you have to host your own wordpress.org blog to customize your theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Art Direction](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/art-direction/) which lets you add custom css on a per post basis. If you use this style on several different pages you should add the styles to a global stylesheet.

Comment: I dont think this is an option if you let wordpress.com host.I think they make this painful so you pay for the "custom css" upgrade.  They allow you to preview style just not apply it.  So i took my "style" block put it in the css layout and it works.. ;(

Comment: I haven't.   Debating writing something to do it (calculate style and apply to html element style attribute), or just pay the 15 dollars.